# Do airlines check if people passing through the gate actually board the plane?

Tags: airport-security

There seems to be a loophole in the system that ensures that checked bags are accompanied by passengers. Suppose that I check in a bag with a bomb, I go to the gate where my boarding pass gets scanned and I then make my way to the plane. However, in some cases you have to go down the stairs, walk on the tarmac to the plane, or you'll be transported by bus to the plane. In these case, it seems to me I could just sneak out and get back to the airport unnoticed.

Comment: I don't think that people that doesn't look like a airport worker should walk outside the plane without being unnoticed

Comment: Normally cabin crew count the number of passengers on board, and reconcile that with the passenger manifest. If the numbers don't match, they work out who's missing, get very grumpy and offload bags. I've seen it happen a few times, normally for people who feel unwell and self-offload

Comment: Also, checked luggage is scanned (at many airports).

Comment: You wouldn't get back unnoticed. And if noticed, you will get a heavy fine and face possible jail time.

Comment: I have had my checked bags opened by TSA at _every_ departure from USA, with things broken every time.  Doesn't matter how carefully I pack, they unwrap it and toss it back in loose.  Then they have to force it closed because it doesn't fit that way.

Comment: In most every case of tarmac boarding there are ground staff watching the passengers as they make their way to the airplane, so wandering away will be quickly noticed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No system is so secure that there are no ways around it. Yes, the loophole you describe sort of exists, but it's not that straightforward in many airports. For one, at pretty much any airport, departing and arriving passengers are strictly separated, making it very difficult to join a crowd of arrivals when you are supposedly departing yourself.

Yes, in some cases, it would be possible to sneak out of a queue, or to not walk towards the airplane, but then you somehow have to get out of the airport, or on board another plane. Depending on the airport, this will not be easy and might result, when caught, in all sorts of safety measures being enacted.

Then, as @Gagravarr points out, cabin crew typically count the number of passengers on board and reconcile this with the passenger manifest.

Having said this, particularly in more out of the way airports, small airports in Africa, for example, safety measures are rather ineffective.

But, not only in out of the way airports: http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/exclusive-150-flight-mexico-skip-customs-leave-jfk-article-1.2443629 and http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3414989/American-Airlines-passengers-arriving-international-flight-JFK-allowed-exit-without-going-Customs.html